# USDC Transaction "Balance" vs. "Token Balance"

Tags: usdc

I initiated a transaction to transfer from an AAVE wallet to USDC address which shows as successful. However, I do not see the balanced transferred to my USDC (Coinbase) address.

Looking on [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/) it shows the transaction value = 0. However, it does show in the "Tokens Transferred" **From** .. **To** [.](https://etherscan.io/token/0x7fc66500c84a76ad7e9c93437bfc5ac33e2ddae9?a=0x52a3c3158f085799c779519ed7355a514d1f24da).. **For** 5.482393108610042552 ($2,608.78) Aave Token (AAVE)

Did I misunderstand how transfers to USDC is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see within the Coinbase settings:

> Important note: Crypto addresses are asset specific. Do not send
> Bitcoin to a Bitcoin Cash address, for example, or your funds will be
> lost.

If you have your own wallet, you can use a decentralised exchange such as Uniswap to perform the token swap (AAVE -> USDC). Once you own USDC, you can then transfer it to your USDC Coinbase address.

If you have both the AAVE and USDC in Coinbase, you can swap directly from there.

I am afraid you might have lost your AAVE tokens if you sent this directly to a USDC address without doing the swap before.

In any case, you can also contact Coinbase to check whether it is somehow possible to access your USDCs.